# Are RSA signatures deterministic?

Tags: rsa, signature

If I sign the word `HELLO` with the mechanism "NONEwithRSA" with the same private key, will I always have the same signature?

A Java example always return different byte array :

```
PKCS11Provider provider = new PKCS11Provider(this);
List<PKCS11Slot> slots = PKCS11Slot.enumerateSlots(provider);
PKCS11Session session = null;

if (slots.size() > 0) {
    session = PKCS11Session.open(slots.get(0),
    PKCS11Session.OPEN_MODE_READ_ONLY);
}

PKCS11KeyStoreSpi keyStore = new PKCS11KeyStoreSpi(provider, "PKCS11");
keyStore.engineLoad(null, "PIN".toCharArray());
PKCS11PrivateKey privateKey = PKCS11PrivateKey.getPrivateKeys(session).get(0);
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA", provider);
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update("HELLO".getBytes(), 0, "HELLO".getBytes().length);
byte[] realSig = signature.sign();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some signature algorithms are deterministic (you always get the same signature for the same private key and input), others are not. In the case of RSA, as specified by [PKCS#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125), the "old-style" (aka "v1.5") signatures are deterministic, while the "new-style" ("PSS") signatures are not (padding includes some random bytes).

In Java, the `"NONEwithRSA"` mechanism ought to select the old-style signatures, and the input data should be already hashed (a normal signature begins by hashing the input data); in your code, you use unhashed data as input, which is a bad idea for security. The `"NONEwithRSA"` mechanism was added to support contexts where data is hashed externally, and also [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246) which insists (in its pre-1.2 versions) on using the concatenation of MD5 and SHA-1 as its "hash function". This does not explain why you get different outputs, but you are still doing it wrong.

To investigate further, convert the signature to a `BigInteger` and apply the public key on it, to see what the padded data looks like:

```
BigInteger n = ... (the public key modulus)
BigInteger e = ... (the public key exponent)
BigInteger x = new BigInteger(1, realSig);
System.out.printf("%X\n", x.modPow(e, n));
```

With PKCS#1 v1.5, this should look like:

```
1FFFFFFFFF....FFFFF0048454C4C4F
```

(The `48454C4C4F` is the encoding of `"HELLO"` -- because your code puts the raw data here instead of the hash value suitably encoded in an ASN.1 structure which designates the hash function.)

Since you are using a PKCS#11, you will sign data depending on what the underlying device can do. It is possible that your device does not allow such `"NONEwithRSA"` mechanism, or allows it only if it already looks like a properly encoded hash value. This may be your issue after all. The debug code above should show what happens.

(Also, don't use `String.getBytes()` without any argument. This converts the input string with the default encoding of the current machine, which depends on how the machine was configured; for some people it will be UTF-8, others will have UTF-16 or latin-1 or something else. It is much better to specify an explicit encoding, as: `s.getBytes("UTF-8")`)

Comment: Stumbled upon this old Q/A. If the string "HELLO" produces probabilistic values for `"NoneWithRSA"` then it is extremely likely that the PKCS#11 uses the `"HELLO"` string placed in uninitialized memory. So resolve this, first encode `"HELLO"` with a pre-established encoding scheme and then pre-  it with a string - even just one containing zeros. Up to the length of the modulus of course - the padding better be secure, or the scheme won't be.